# sticky header is shaking while scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm facing a problem with the position sticky. I try to do header shrink while scrolling but the header is shaking.

But when I change to `position: fixed` it's working fine. what's the problem with sticky?

I'm updating the height style while scrolling.

I have added the StackBlitz link to reproduce the problem.

### JSX

```
    <>
      <div id="header">Header</div>
    </>
```

```
      useEffect(() => {
        function scrollFunction() {
          if (window.scrollY > 50) {
            document.getElementById('header').style.height = '45px';
          } else {
            document.getElementById('header').style.height = '90px';
          }
        }

        window.addEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction);
        return () => {
          window.removeEventListener('scroll', scrollFunction);
        };
      }, []);
```

### CSS

```
#header {
  background-color: #f1f1f1; 
  padding: 10px 10px;
  color: black;
  text-align: center; 
  font-size: 90px;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: sticky; 
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; 
  transition: 0.2s;
}
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-yzz1hi?file=src%2FApp.css)

[image]

Comment: Please include the relevant code in the question itself. An external source is okay in addition, but shouldn't be the only way for us to see the code.

Comment: Unable to check your code as of the time I comment this. Perhaps you can share just the part of code that create this shrinking sticky header?

Comment: yes I updated the stackblitz link

Comment: Works fine on my browser

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet** using the `<>` icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes I updated the relevant code

Comment: Not quite, the HTML is missing... That's why we have Stack Snippets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, what is happening here is that when the `window.scrollY` gets past 50 and the height of the `header` is reduced, the value of `window.scrollY` also gets reduced (because the scroller moves up) due to that reduced height.

When the header is in this transition area, both the `if` and `else` statements keep executing because of the change in `window.scrollY`. (the `transition: 0.2s;` makes it worse) You can confirm this by checking the elements in the dev tools.

I don't know any solution for this, but maybe you can ignore it as we need to scroll carefully to the point of the transition to reproduce this, normally it should not happen and no one will notice it. Or you could create another sticky header that will appear after scrolling past the main header.

Answer (score 0):

@Akshay is correct, but there is a solution to this.
You can add a transition in CSS so it won't lag. This is how you can add the transition.

You will need to add this to the nav bar for the transition:

```
transition: height 0.4s linear;
```

Comment: It isn't working for me.